# Building libraries with bazel and hardcoding dependencies into them

Tags: gcc, bazel, dynamic-linking

Is it possible to hard code dependencies into the libraries build with bazel. The reason is that if I build somelib I can use it in the workspace but as soon as I copy the lib somewhere else I loose all dependencies (bazel cache). Witch creates a problem when I want to deploy the libraries into the system or install.

```
some_folder
|
thirdparty
|_WORKSPACE
|_somelib
|    |_src
|         |_ a.c
|         |_ BUILD
|    |_include
|         |_a.h
|_include
   |_ b.h
```

Comment: You can use the `tree` command in Bash to generate ASCII folder diagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to build a fully statically linked library. This can be done in Bazel by building the library using `cc_binary` with the `linkshared` attribute set to `True`. According to the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.linkshared) you also have to name your library `libfoo.so` or similar.

What enables the static library here is `cc_binary`'s `linkstatic` attributes behavior. When `True`, which is the default, all dependencies that can be linked statically into the binary will be. Note that `linkstatic` does NOT behave the same on `cc_library`, see the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_binary.linkstatic).

So, basically you want something like this in your BUILD file

```
cc_binary(
    name = "libfoo.so",
    srcs = [...],
    hdrs = [...],
    linkshared = 1,
    #linkstatic = 1 # This is the default, you don't need to add this.
)
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ok. You got me to read the documentation more carefully. But you are kind of a saying that bazel builds the symlinks into the libraries for dynamic linking, and any other library should be staticly defined?

Comment: Yeah, kinda. For dynamic libraries, the program binary that depends on them tries to find them at runtime. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html for more information. When libraries are built for static linking, they are compiled separately from other code. When a program uses them that separately compiled library is fully included in the program binary, creating a larger final binary but which does not need the library installed on the system.

Comment: I figured it out but the idea is a bit tricky and uses shell.

Comment: I'd be interested into you solution.

Answer (score 0):

just like Sebastian said (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001169/14492972), you can use cc_binary + linkshared=True to build a library that will include all dependencies so that you won't have to link all external libraries separately. However, cc_binary doesn't have hdrs (headers) argument. You should add the header file that you want to be included for library usage in srcs.